# How to reference class Classname<T> where T : Interface

Tags: c#

Is it possible to reference and initialize this class for me to be able to run this

```
internal class Classname <T> where T : Interface, new()
```

to my Program.cs file where this code is declared?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

I have tried declaring this code but gets an error.

```
Classname name = new Classname();
```

Comment: Well you can't refer to it without a specific type argument, no. You need `Classname<Something> x = new Classname<Something>();` where `Something` is a class deriving from `Interface`, and with a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Additionally, *any* time you ask a question about an error, *include the complete error message in the question*.

Comment: Please refer to the [documentation of generic types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics), I don't think there's even a SO question to cover this basic problem you have at the moment.